# To fill space between these two curves in Gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Code

```
set xrange [2014:2050]; set yrange [80:110]; 
set terminal qt size 560,270; set grid; 
set offset 1,1,0,0; 
inc(x) = 0.439 * x - 800.65; 
re(x) = 1.0025 * 83.3 * 1.005**(-2014 + x); 
plot re(x) w filledcurves, inc(x) w filledcurves;
```

and I get

[image]

which is wrong. 
The parameter selection must be wrong, although it seems to work [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_cvs/fillbetween.html).

**How can you cover the space between the two graphs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filling between two curves works only for data. To use it also for functions, you must use the special file name `+`:

```
set xrange [2014:2050]; set yrange [80:110]; 
set grid; 
set offset 1,1,0,0; 
inc(x) = 0.439 * x - 800.65; 
re(x) = 1.0025 * 83.3 * 1.005**(-2014 + x); 
plot '+' using 1:(re($1)):(inc($1)) w filledcurves
```

[image]